# PageRank tool for large graphs

Tags: machine-learning, pagerank

I need to compute the PageRank scores for a large graph which cannot be loaded into memory. I need a simple toolkit that can be easily modified, since I need to change its code in my research. Are you aware of any useful and simple toolkit that computes PageRank for large graphs (the size of graph is around 40 GB).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Two packages you might want to evaluate are

1. Apache TinkerPop
   http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#pagerankvertexprogram
2. Apache Spark - GraphX
   http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#pagerank

Both are open source with Apache license, so the source code is available for you to modify or extend.